# parsing text with html tags using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

to parse an html element to be used in after click the submit , i m using this method

```
 $panel = $('.box').html();
 $("#page").append('<form  name="sampleForm" method="post" action="ticket.form.php"><input type="hidden" name="ConfirmationPanel" value=""></form>');

    document.sampleForm.ConfirmationPanel.value = $panel;
    document.forms["sampleForm"].submit();
```

and then after the submit click , i'm requesting the POST variable , and insert the content text of the POST variable to the page :

```
 var $_POST = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
if($_POST["ConfirmationPanel"].length > 0)
{
$('#tabspanel').before($_POST['ConfirmationPanel']);
}
```

i can successfully access to the variable and also use it , and the every thing is fine , one probléme is , jquery insert the content of the POST variable like text , like this ("`<div><h1>Test</h1></div>`") , what i want is to insert it like this (`<div><h1>Test</h1></div>`) without the ( " " ) , so to be one of the page html elemnts

otherwise : 
 i insert the text from the POST variable befor `$('#tabspanel')` , jquery insert it as a text like this : `<div id="tabspanel" >"<div><h1>Test</h1></div>"</div>` , i want jquery to insert it as html element until i can see the (div) and the (h1) , so to be like this : `<div id="tabspanel" ><div><h1>Test</h1></div></div>` –

Comment: @ManseUK i know that , and that's why  i'm parsing the javascript variables to the a POST variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the post variable from a different PHP page.  Eg ajax the form results to another PHP page, then return the success/failure of it as plain text and test against it in the current page.

Comment: i can successfully access to the variable and also use it , and the every thing is fine , one probléme is , jquery insert the content of the POST variable like text , like this ( "<div><h1>Test</h1></div>" ) , what i want is to insert it like this ( <div><h1>Test</h1></div> ) without the ( " " )

Comment: Ah sorry I miss understood, easy to do just do a js replace on the variable : `$myvar.replace(new RegExp('"', "g"), '')`

Comment: i have a lot of (") , i just want jquery to read the POST variable as HTML elements , so after the insert , to be one of the page html elemnts , and not like a Text with ("....")

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  What you've posted doesn't quite fit with the question and also doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: after i insert the text from the POST variable  befor $('#tabspanel') , jquery insert it as a text like this : <div id="tabspanel" >"<div><h1>Test</h1></div>"</div> , i want jquery to insert it as html element until i can see the (div) and the (h1) , so to be like this : <div id="tabspanel" ><div><h1>Test</h1></div></div>

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting anything from the $_post variable it looks like a combo of js and php.  Can you post the full code.